# jQuery keyup - multiple inputs and pass id name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a number of input id's in a form as follows (example, not complete form) This is for a Chrome Extension so I cannot modify the form.

```
<form>
  <input id="data-draft-brand-name" />
  <input id="data-draft-name-en-us" />
  <input id="data-draft-bullet-points-bullet1-en-us" />
  <input id="data-draft-bullet-points-bullet2-en-us" />
  <input id="data-draft-description-en-us" />
</form>
```

What I am doing is using keyup on each on the inputs, and then doing the same thing for each id like so:

```
$( "#data-draft-description-en-us" ).keyup(function() {
  var currentVal = $(this).val();
  currentVal = currentVal.toLowerCase();

  var currentLength = currentVal.length;
  currentLength = 2000 - currentLength;

  $('#description-count').text(`${currentLength} characters left`);

  if(currentVal.indexOf('word') !== -1) {
    $('#data-draft-description-en-us').css('border','1px solid red');
    $('#data-draft-description-en-us').css('background','red');
  } else {
    $('#data-draft-description-en-us').css('border','1px solid #a6a6a6');
    $('#data-draft-description-en-us').css('background','none');
  }
});
```

As you can see, there will be a lot of repetition.  Is there anyway I can pass an array of id's to keyup, and then access the id in the function.  Some pseudo code as an example..

```
$(["#data-draft-brand-name","#data-draft-name-en-us"]).keyup(function(inputID) {
  $(inputID).css('border','1px solid red');
}
```

Comment: Create a loop, check which inputs have a value. Then take those inputs which have a value and get the ID from them. Then, run those ID's through the function?

Comment: I would add a data attribute to group them work and bind to that? `data-draft-input` then use `$("[data-draft-input]").keyup(function() {`

Comment: well ids are singular so.... not sure how they can repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```
$("#data-draft-brand-name, #data-draft-name-en-us").keyup(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#' + id).css('border','1px solid red');
});
```

No need to provide square brackets `[]`, `id` should be separated by comma.

Here you go with `jsfiddle` https://jsfiddle.net/tjkah0ck/2/

```js
$( "#data-draft-brand-name, #data-draft-name-en-us" ).keyup(function() {
    var currentVal = $(this).val();
        currentVal = currentVal.toLowerCase();
    console.log(currentVal);
    var currentLength = currentVal.length;
        currentLength = 2000 - currentLength;

    $('#description-count').text(`${currentLength} characters left`);

    if(currentVal.indexOf('word') !== -1) {
        $('#data-draft-description-en-us').css('border','1px solid red');
        $('#data-draft-description-en-us').css('background','red');
    } else {
        $('#data-draft-description-en-us').css('border','1px solid #a6a6a6');
        $('#data-draft-description-en-us').css('background','none');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
   <input id="data-draft-brand-name"/>
   <input id="data-draft-name-en-us"/>
   <input id="data-draft-bullet-points-bullet1-en-us" />
   <input id="data-draft-bullet-points-bullet2-en-us" />
   <input id="data-draft-description-en-us" />
</form>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This doesn't appear to trigger anything at all.  Have tried to log out inputID but nothing

Comment: @K20GH I've updated the answer. Is your input textboxes are dynamically getting generated?

Comment: I didn't negative vote you.  I've actually just submitted an edit to your first code block as it differed from the second.  It now works :)

Comment: @K20GH I know that you haven't down vote, someone else without any reason. I've updated the answer have a look. Instead of getting id using `inputID.currentTarget.i`, please use `$(this).attr('id');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use start with selector for attribute, [name^=”value”] [https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/][1]
If we need to edit your code then it should be below

```
$( "div[id^='data-draft-'" ).keyup(function() {
var currentInput = $(this);
var currentVal = $(this).val();
    currentVal = currentVal.toLowerCase();
console.log(currentVal);
var currentLength = currentVal.length;
    currentLength = 2000 - currentLength;

$('#description-count').text(`${currentLength} characters left`);

if(currentVal.indexOf('word') !== -1) {
    currentInput.css('border','1px solid red');
    currentInput.css('background','red');
} else {
    currentInput.css('border','1px solid #a6a6a6');
    currentInput.css('background','none');
}
});
```

Enjoy

Answer (score -2):

To realize what you want, you should use a `class` to define which `input` will have a `keyup` event handler.

Also, you can retreive the id of the current `input` by calling `attr("id")`.

So you'll have a code like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".keupinput").keyup(function(event) {
    var inputid = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log("I'm the " + inputid + " input.");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
   <input class="keupinput" id="data-draft-brand-name" />
   <input class="keupinput" id="data-draft-name-en-us" />
   <input class="keupinput" id="data-draft-bullet-points-bullet1-en-us" />
   <input class="keupinput" id="data-draft-bullet-points-bullet2-en-us" />
   <input class="keupinput" id="data-draft-description-en-us" />
</form>
```

Comment: As a general side-note, in a well organized company/team don't use classes for functional code. CSS/Style guys will remove/add them on a whim. For functional use in code only use data attributes, identifiers and similar as the CSS/Style Guys won't touch those.

Comment: Also, `this.id` will do just fine